# Group function in select with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following select :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                   max(tctc_cntipcli) as "TypeOfContract" ,
                   max(texe_cncclipu) as "ContractNumber",
                   max(tctc_cndocidc) as "ClientName",
                   max(tsrv_cndesser) as "ServiceName",
                   max(texe_cnfuncid) as "ServiceNumber",
                   tsrs_cnsubsdc as "SubserviceName",
                   texe_cnsubser as "SubserviceNumber",
                   tmap_cndesc   as "Map",
        (
        SELECT DECODE(to_char(count(tlof_cnlofrid)), '0', 'NA', COUNT(TLOF_CNLOFRID))
        from service.kndtlof
        where tlof_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
        and tlof_cnservic = texe_cnfuncid
        and tlof_cnsubser = texe_cnsubser
        and tlof_cnfhalta > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
       ) as "VolumeOffilesMessages"
                          from service.kndtctc, service.kndtexe, service.kndtscm, service.kndtsrv, service.kndtsrs, service.kndtmap
                          where tctc_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser
                          and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
                          and tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco
                          and tscm_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
                          and tscm_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and tctc_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and texe_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrv_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrs_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tscm_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tmap_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          group by tsrs_cnsubsdc, texe_cnsubser, tmap_cndesc
                          order by texe_cncclipu;
```

which is outputting :

```
    C|50000614|Lindsey|InformationReporting|3050|940PreviousDay|I1|BAISameDayWire|N                                  
C|50000614|Lindsey|WirePayments|3001|WireStatus|S1|MT101SWIFTStatus|NA                                     
C|50000614|Lindsey|WirePayments|3001|WirePayments|W1|Sungard820Payment|NA
```

I need to use max on columns 1, 2, 3 and where duplicating columns 4 and 5 to make the output look as below:

```
C|50000614|Lindsey|InformationRep|3050|PreviousDay |I1|BAISameDayWire   |NA
                   WirePayments  |3001|WireStatus  |S1|MT101SWIFTStatus |NA                                     
                                       WirePayments|W1|Sungard820Payment|NA
```

I have tried the max on the selected columns in the outer query and keep getting "ora 0037 : not a single-group group function" error. Thanks.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Im sure you can create a smaller sample with same behaviour. Instead of writing such a long query and expecting we spend hours trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX` is an analytic function. This means it computes a single value based on a set of rows. Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm) page for documentation on the function itself, and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) page for info on analytic functions. You're going to have to group the data according to your spec using a `GROUP BY` statement, otherwise you will encounter the error ORA-00937, just as you were before.

Comment: i did max the selected columns in the outer select and group by in the from clause, but it still errors with ORA-00979 : not a GROUP BY expression?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading your query and understanding what you're trying to do, but I can tell you that you're probably going to want to do a single `MAX (...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` in there, rather than calling `MAX` on 5 columns. Play around with that syntax a little bit and see if you get the output you're looking for.